# Prove that $G$ is an Abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I would need help for this one. I've been stuck on this exercise:

> If $G$ is a group with $a,b,c,x,y \in G$ where $xay=bac \implies xy = bc$. Prove that this group $G$ is Abelian.

Can someone give me a tip on where to start? I literally have no clue how to start proving this. Thanks and sorry for bad formatting. I'm new.

Comment: You should try harder to [avoid no clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: Is your statement quantified over all such $5-$tuples of elements?

Answer (score 4):

Let $a=x^{-1}$, $b=y$ and $c=x$. The remaining statement is quantified over only $x$ and $y$. See what it says.